# Layout editor does not pass styleable attribute to custom View class

Tags: android, graphical-layout-editor, declare-styleable

I am creating a `FixedAspectImageView` to solve the problem in Android of making an `ImageView` set its view bounds to match the aspect ratio of the image contained within, *and also* fill an arbitrarily wide (or tall) available area and stretch the image appropriately.  In the current version I'm sending a floating point "ratio" parameter from the layout, though eventually I would intend to detect the ratio of the image.

However, I am having trouble with the styleable attributes.  My attrs.xml has this:

```
<resources>
    <!-- other stuff, which bizarrely works -->
    <declare-styleable name="FixedAspectImageView">
        <attr name="ratio" format="float"/>
    </declare-styleable>    
</resources>
```

My constructor looks like:

```
public FixedAspectImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if(attrs!=null) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FixedAspectImageView);
        if(a.hasValue(R.styleable.FixedAspectImageView_ratio)) {
            setRatio(a.getFloat(R.styleable.FixedAspectImageView_ratio, 1.f));
        }
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

(and very similarly for the one with an integer defStyle at the end) and my layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mypackage="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.package"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.my.package.view.FixedAspectImageView
            android:id="@+id/fixedAspectImageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/picture_of_goatse"
            mypackage:ratio="1.2329" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've determined that `setRatio(Float)` works, because if I set a value in the source the measurement system works perfectly.  The TypedArray being passed in has no indices set.  What's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout editor does not always pick up `<declare-styleable>` attributes straight away.  Restarting eclipse fixed the problem.  The above code was all correct; the package name should obviously be the package of the project for the namespace in the layout, and the custom `View` will use generated values from `R.styleable`.

Known issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52298